# How can I add authentication on my project using an already exist user table in ASP.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, identity

I can't build Identity on a user table already exist and I could not modify the user table within Identity

I created the models and then I generated Controls and Views.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfho6.png

Then I try to create a new identity through add new scaffolded item, but I could not use the already existing user table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMe91.png

And I also tried to create a new project and create the Identity first and then modify the Identity user table by adding some columns and then create my tables on the same context, but I will not find the user model to modify it and create the relationships with the other entities.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password doesn't match, Type again !")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [CustomDate(ErrorMessage = "Use Correct Birthdate")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public bool Eanble { get; set; }
    public string Permissions { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime UpdateAt { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public List<Consultation> Consultations { get; set; }


    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public List<ConsultationComment> ConsultationComments { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach.
In order to add your own custom properties to the user you should create a class which derives from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser. There you can add your own custom properties which would be added to the table. Here is how you can do it:

```
// using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; is needed
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Age { get; set; } 
}
```

Now you should create a class which derives from IdentityDbContext:

```
 public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This is basically a DbContext with 2 DbSets that Identity will use.

Then go to your Startup.cs and add the following line inside ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

Now you can build your project and see the changes applied to your database. You can not remove Identity properties, but you can add your own.

Comment: Thanks, but i get **"InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application"** when adding **"services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>();"** in ConfigureServices.

Comment: @AdelSaadEddin I updated the answer. It should work now.